# As of this morning varnish is not listening on configured port 80

Tags: port, varnish

I've had varnish running on my site for awhile now configured to listen on port 80 and apache on port 8080. This morning I noticed that varnish is now listening on port 6081. When I `systemctl restart varnish` it still is listening on port 6081.

`ps aux | grep varnish`

```
vcache    1010  0.0  0.0  18524 11620 ?        SLs  14:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
vcache    1023  0.0  0.0 286156 68660 ?        SLl  14:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
root      2248  0.0  0.0   3084   896 pts/0    S+   14:53   0:00 grep varnish
varnish+  4593  0.1  0.0  86596  1144 ?        Ss   06:57   0:32 /usr/bin/varnishncsa -a -w /var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log -D -P /run/varnishncsa/varnishncsa.pid
```

`/etc/default/varnish`

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,48G"
```

How can I get varnish to listen on the configured port and also find out why this happened?

**Update**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30618749/5749974) solved the issue. I had to modify `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/varnish.service`. But now my question is why? Not exactly sure what this file is or why it had port 6081 in it.

Comment: So what do you get when you run 'systemctl cat varnish.service'? As root, if you 'lsof -Pni:80 | grep LISTEN', do you see any other process running on port 80? Is Apache httpd still listening on port 8080?

Comment: After modifying the user.target.wants file when I run `systemctl cat varnish.service` i get: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m` and also `WantedBy=multi-user.target`. And yes when running the lsof command I only have varnish listening on port 80 and apache on port 8080. So the issue is fixed now, just wondering why I had to modify that user.target.wants file.

Comment: @TimothyFisher `/etc/default/varnish` is the old way, the pre-systemd way. Have you performed any OS upgrades recently that could have prioritized systemd over the old sysv config files? FYI: `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish` will allow you to see the full service file and `sudo systemctl edit varnish` will present potential overrides.